# What is the jizo in the main courtyard for?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

In "Bowser's Kingdom" in *Super Mario Odyssey*, there are a few puzzles that involve capturing jizo statues and maneuvering them into different positions.

However, there's *also* a jizo in the Main Courtyard, behind the small building to the right of the arrival point (just before the two circles where the Broodal fights happened).

[image: Picture showing location]

What's the purpose of this one? I haven't found anything I can use it for, and it can't move very far before running into an obstacle it can't jump over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several spots on the ground that you only can stomp with the jizo statue to get different things, these are:

> A king heart
>   8 golden mini gumbas
>   1 coin (6 times)

There is nothing special like a moon hidden for it, the purpose seems to be the king heart.

Comment: It is possible to collect the moon from the broodal fights with it, but it is not a requirement and you cannot fight the broodals using the statue, it is a lot easier to just collect the moon as Mario.

Comment: From a game design perspective it seems to be likely that it is the first jizo statue for many people, which gives them an opportunity to try it out in a safe environment, this is not confirmed and it is just an idea that I had while looking for possible purposes